# Can I just stop using datetime.date entirely?

Tags: python, date, datetime

In Python, it's my impression that `datetime.date` is basically just a subset of `datetime.datetime`, with fewer features and slightly less overhead. I'd like to never use `datetime.date` again for the following reasons:

- No more conversions between the two types!
- `datetime.date` objects are always timezone-unaware, for obvious reasons. This makes it harder to generalize timezone handling across an entire application, if sometimes you're using `datetime.date` and sometimes you're using `datetime.datetime`
- On multiple occasions I've encountered headaches accidentally comparing `datetime.date` objects and `datetime.datetime` objects. Always using only one type makes comparisons simpler.
- Formatting differences between `datetime.date` and `datetime.datetime` should be a *formatting* issue only. Carrying the difference further down into the underlying class introduces an unnecessary complexity to the language.
- If I'm on the right track about this, then `datetime.date` will eventually be deprecated in future releases of Python, just like `unicode` and `long` have been. Adopting this convention now puts me ahead of the curve.

It seems to me that the only compelling argument for continuing to use `datetime.date` is small amount of extra memory and storage involved in `datetime.datetime`. Let's say that I don't care about this extra overhead. Are there any other very compelling reasons to keep using this class? I don't want to switch to this convention and then regret it later because I missed something important.

Comment: I actually see this an argument for never using ```time``` either.

Comment: As a side note, `unicode` was not deprecated. In 2.7, it's still the recommended way to deal with Unicode text, and in 3.0 it was renamed to `str` and became the primary string type.

Comment: A `time` is a whole different issue, but it's _also_ worth continuing to use. What `datetime` object could you use to represent something that happens at 12:30 every day?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They represent different things.

A `datetime` is a specific point in time.

A `date` is an *interval* in time. It's not 00:00:00 on that day, it's the *entire day*.

That's why you can't directly convert between them. And that's why you cannot use `datetime` as a substitute for `date`.

(The fact that the same `timedelta` type is used for both is probably a flaw in the module, which has been discussed a few times, but I doubt that it will ever be corrected.)

Comment: I was going to say...a ```timedelta``` is an interval in time.

Comment: I was writting up a long answer, but this is basically is. Dates aren't datetimes. Think of a birthday, it has no time component so adding one make managing a birthday object with a `datetime` more difficult than just using a `date`.

Comment: @galarant: No, a `timedelta` is a _duration_. An _interval_ has a start and an endpoint. A `datetime` and a `timedelta` together may define an interval.

Comment: I disagree:
1) You actually were born at a specific time, not just on a day.
2) If you didn't care about the time you were born and just the day, then you can use 1981-09-20T00:00:00+00:00

Comment: Leaving this out of the answer, but… there are also some practical differences, even if you wanted to fake `date`s with `datetime`s at 00:00:00 and `day`-based `timedelta`s with second-based `timedelta`s—e.g., 86400 hours after midnight can still be the same day if there's a leap second or a DST transition.

Comment: @galarant: Do you celebrate your birthday at the time you were born, at midnight, or throughout the day? Unless it's the last one, you must have some really short birthday parties…

Comment: @abarnert: Conceptually is nothing special about the time *interval* of one day, except maybe convenience and history. In my opinion those are not good reasons to use a type.

Comment: @abarnert: Five minutes is also an interval. Should there be a ```five_minute``` type?

Comment: @galarant: If you're arguing that Python should have a general-purpose time interval type, and `date` should just be a special case of that, then you're right; it's an especially convenient and useful special case, but no more than that. But that doesn't in any way mean it's the same as a time point; in fact, it argues the opposite.

Comment: @galarant: No, five minutes is not an interval, it's a duration. You're still confusing the two. The five minutes starting at 2014-01-08Z23:57:14 and ending right before 2014-01-09Z00:02:14 are an open interval of five minutes' duration. See [interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)) at Wikipedia for for information.

Comment: No I wouldn't say I'm arguing that. It seems that any logic involved in what you're calling a *duration* can be written with a combination of ```datetime``` and ```timedelta``` so there's no need for any duration types at all, not even a general one.

Comment: @galarant: That link is primarily about intervals in the real number line rather than the time line, but it's basically the same idea, except that you call durations "diameters" in set theory terms or "differences" in analysis terms.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44920/discussion-between-galarant-and-abarnert)

Answer (score 12):

This is the precise relationship:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> issubclass(datetime.datetime, datetime.date)
True
```

If you don't want to use `date`, simply don't.  There are many applications in which the "small amount of extra memory and storage involved" for a `datetime` is a significant burden, especially when a massive number of `date`s need to be stored in a database as pickles (e.g., in ZODB in a Zope installation - and it's not coincidental that Zope Corp paid the then-PythonLabs team to design & implement the `datetime` module to begin with ;-) ).

**EDIT - what a `date` "means"**

I want to push back a bit on @abamert's "A `date` is an *interval* in time. It's not 00:00:00 on that day, it's the *entire* day."  You're certainly free to think of it that way, but there was no such *intent*.  I wrote almost all of the original `datetime` module (both the Python and C versions), working with the primary module designers:  Guido van Rossum and Jim Fulton.

Guido was very keen on the notion of "naive" dates and times, an everyday "common sense" notion of dates and times that simply ignores all the tedious subtleties geeks like to obsess over ;-) (like historical time zone - and even calendar - adjustments, and "leap seconds" of no actual use to anyone save astronomers).  To him, the best way to know what a date was *intended* to mean is to ask a 12-year-old.  And their answer doesn't matter.  If they think `date(2014, 1, 9)` means "the entire day", fine.  If they like to think of it as the stroke of midnight at the start of the day, also fine.  Ditto midnight at the end of the day, or noon, or 3pm nap time, or different times on different days, or no time at all attached ... those distinctions are all in *your* head so far as `date` is concerned.  `date` doesn't encourage or discourage any of them.

Now a geek may object "but if I think of `date(2014, 1, 9)` as being noon and you think of `date(2014, 1, 10)` as being 3pm, subtracting them returns a wrong answer!".  Yawn.  Ask a 12-year-old:  it's obvious that, for naive dates, the difference is exactly 1 (naive) day.

There's nothing here suggesting that any particular person or application "should" find that useful.  Many applications *do* find it useful.  If yours isn't one of them, don't use it.

All in all, the only major regret I have about `datetime` is that `tzinfo` objects have no reliable way to distinguish between "standard" and "daylight" times during the ambiguous transition hours.  Guido's sense of frugality was offended (overly so, in my opinion) by that a C `struct tm` "wasted" an entire `int` (`tm_isdst`) for this 1 bit of information only needed to disambiguate transition times.  It's not a coincidence that most geographical areas that switch between "daylight" and "standard" times make these transitions when most people are asleep, so for almost all practical purposes the ambiguities are invisible ("what do you mean, 2:10am? is that the first time the clock read 2:10am, or the second time after we set the clock back an hour from 3am to 2am again?").  But for those few who really do care, living without that bit remains a royal pain :-(

Comment: _All in all, the only major regret I have about datetime is that tzinfo objects have no reliable way to distinguish between "standard" and "daylight" times during the ambiguous transition hours._

It took a long time, but we are about to fix that with [PEP 495](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0495).